# Pyglet window will not redraw on resize

Tags: python-2.7, pyglet

I have a class that is subclassed to pyglet.window.Window, and I need it to be a resizable window. I figured out how to enable it to be resized, but I need to make it redraw everything on the screen when I actually do resize it. Here's what I have so far:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Application()

    @window.event()
    def on_resize(x,y):
        window.label.x = window.WindowSize[0]/2
        window.label.y = window.WindowSize[1]*15/16

    @window.event()
    def on_draw():
        window.clear()
        window.label.draw()
        for control in window.controls:
            control.draw()

    pyglet.app.run()
```

so we make our window and then have those two window events. I hope I did that right--I'm fairly new to pyglet. As I said, the main problem is that when I resize the window it doesn't actually change anything unless I press one of the buttons on the window which changes the positions.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer exactly without knowing what is going on within Application, but, the Pyglet event loop will only dispatch on_draw for windows that are invalid so you could try adding

```
window.invalid = True
```

In on_resize and see if that helps.

Additionally you can find more info about window.invalid in the Pyglet source here:
https://code.google.com/p/pyglet/source/browse/pyglet/window/__init__.py#362